# Formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

I have an excelsheet that contains thousands of records.In one particular column(Coulmn F) i have to use a formula which contains the values of column A,B,C,D.I have attached the screenshot.How to use the formula.My requirement is in Column F,it will show values from column A,B,C,D something like this:- Exec ChangeStatus('A2',B2,C2,D2);. i need column B and c as DateTime in format of dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS. :-[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are looking for this?

```
="Exec ChangeStatus("&A2&","&TEXT(B2, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss")&","&TEXT(C2, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss")&","&D2&")"
```

Comment: one problem in above formula that i need column B and c as DateTime in format of dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS

Comment: Formatting is language dependent and something you have to check yourself. Goto Cell B1 and check the cell format. Then use the same format in the TEXT(B2,"format") formula. In your case it could be French so it might be: "jj/mm/aaaa UU:MM:SS" but I can't be sure.

Comment: Can we use to_date function instead of text,when i am using to_date(B2,"dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS") or text(B2,"dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS"),it shows error in formula

Comment: Most likely, Excel will have problems with this format [See this link](http://communities.rightnow.com/posts/9922650a08). In this article they also tried to_date. How did you get the right formmat in Cell B2 then?